# block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant API::V1::Users (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, grape-api

Im trying to set up api endpoints for my rails application and keep receiving this error my environment is Ruby 2.6 and Rails 5.2 and im using the 'grape' gem for the api here is the blog I followed to set it up. https://medium.com/@ryanwaldorf/how-to-add-an-api-to-an-existing-rails-app-1d2419ba91bd

here is a link to my repo https://github.com/jslack2537/apiDemoApp

I believe the issue is wither in my config/routes.rb or my application.rb files.

But I could be totally wrong. This is a challenge app and not going to be used in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mainly occurs when naming conventions doesn't match. Try changing `api/v1/user.rb` to `api/v1/users.rb` which also the blog suggests. You missed a 's'.

Comment: Thanks cant say I'm surprised I missed that